# correlated queries in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Not quite sure how to write this query and I thought someone would be so kind as to assist me.

I have two tables (The column names have been changed for security):

## message table

messageid
carbon_copy_id
senderid
recipientid

## carbon_copy table

carbon_copy_id
member_id

Essentially I am writing an email system that allows carbon copies.

- When a member sends a message to one recipient, it writes one record to the message table, leaving the carbon_copy_id null.
- When a member sends an email that has more than one recipient, say for eg 2 recipients, 
  I insert two records into the carbon copy table with the same carbon_copy_id and a member_id for each recipient. I then insert two message records, one for each recipient into the message table with the shared carbon_copy_id i inserted into the carbon copy table.

  select
      mt.messageid,
      mt.carbon_copy_id,
      oa.member_list
  from
      message_table mt
      outer apply (select stuff((select ', ' + cast(cc.member_id as varchar)
                                 from carbon_copy cc
                                 where cc.carbon_copy_id = mt.carbon_copy_id
                                 order by cc.member_id
                                 for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,''))oa(member_list)
  where
      messageid = id_of_message
  order by
      messageid desc

I would need this to be one record with the memberlist where carbon copy was not null, one record without it where it is null.

However, given the paradigm outlined above, this will produce a list of the two records inserted. What I am looking to do is have the result set combine the two records into one and return a comma delimited list of the carbon_copied member ids where carbon_copy_id in the message record is not null.

The idea is to return a list of messages and not display duplicate messages when the message is carbon copied. Similar to how GMAIL does it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, from a design perspective it seems backward to have the message table foreign keyed to the cc table. It should probably be the other way around, with the cc table referencing the messageid of the message that you want to store additional recipients for.

That said, either way you really should use two queries here- one for the message, and one for the list of cc'd recipients. This is a better solution than returning a comma delimited list with either table design.